# How to synchronize a git branch with master?

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I currently have a git repository at github that stores the packaging files for a bunch of packages with a directory structure like this:

```
package-a
  `- PKGBUILD
package-b
  `- PKGBUILD
package-c
  `- PKGBUILD
xorg
  `- PKGBUILD
libx11
  `- PKGBUILD
```

I created an experimental branch, `newxorg`, that contains packaging files for a new version of `xorg` and `libx11` and also updated `package-a` and `package-b` on `master`. My history is something like this:

```
M1 -- M2 -- M3 -- M4
       \
        B1 -- B2

where:
B1 = "Update xorg"
B2 = "Update libx11"
M3 = "Update package-a"
M4 = "Update package-b"
```

Ideally, I'd like my new branch to contain the `M3` and `M4` commits from `master`, like this:

```
M1 -- M2 -- M3 -- M4
                   \
                    B1 -- B2
```

But the problem is that I've already pushed both `master` and the `newxorg` branch to the remote github server. Since people have already cloned the new branch, I'm guessing a rebase would really screw things up for them. What would be the best way to merge the new commits from master?

Comment: Are people cloning both your newxorg branch as well or just your master?

Comment: @omit: Yes people are cloning both newxorg and master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there aren't too many new commits on `master` I would [**cherry-pick**](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-cherry-pick.html) them on `newxorg`.

Following your example, cherry picking  **M3** and **M4** from `master` on `newxorg` would get you from:

```
M1 -- M2 -- M3 -- M4
   \
    B1 -- B2
```

to:

```
M1 -- M2 -- M3 -- M4
   \
    B1 -- B2 -- M3 -- M4
```

You will have **M3 and M4 separately** on `newxorg`.

**With cherry-pick** you would **have a "small" problem** if you decide to **merge** `newxorg` into master (at a later stage) since cherry-pick would create other commits identical in every point to the original **M3** and **M4** commits, BUT with **a different sha1** hash. You (and others) will see this in the history as duplicate commits...

There is also the option of **merging** `master` into `newxorg` (but that would create another merge commit so it isn't exactly what you asked for).

In your case I would prefer to **use the merging method to avoid later problems**.

Choose whatever method you see fit.

---

### LE. Merging details

As you requested, here are a bit more details about the merging method:

1. checkout the `newxorg` branch (`git checkout newxorg`)
2. merge `master` into `newxorg` (`git merge master`)

If you have problems checking out the `newxorg` branch you might need to **[stash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-stash)** the changes you have in your working copy: `git stash` and when you need those changes back you can do a `git stash pop` (`pop` applies the changes and then **discards** the stash) or a `git stash apply` (`apply` applies the changes and **keeps** the stash).

Here is the **initial setup**:

[image: initial setup]

and the **final setup**:

[image: final setup]

At a later stage, when you want to merge back `newxorg` into `master` use these commands:

```
git checkout master
git merge newxorg
```

If you will have conflicts when merging you can use the `git mergetool` to resolve the conflicts. You might need to configure a visual merge tool such as [**p4merge**](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce_visual_merge_and_diff_tools) (which is cross-platform).

**PS.** in case you're wondering where did I get those screenshots from: they are from [**your repository on github**](https://github.com/chenxiaolong/Unity-for-Arch/network).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you explain a little more about the merging method? `newxorg` will eventually be merged into `master` when everything is stable.

Comment: @ChenXiao-Long: done, if you still have questions don't hesitate to ask... either here in comments or as another question (if it's another problem). Also don't forget to check out the answers to the other git questions. You might be surprised how much you can learn from those. I surely did :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! You made everything very clear :) I'll be sure to check out the answers to other git questions.

Comment: I see "thank you"... and no up votes. Just mine, now.